# COCOA: Application helper is not getting launched at user login

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Please allow me to elaborate:

**Goal**

I want my application helper to launch at startup (user login)

**What I am doing**

I am using `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` to set my application helper to set as login item using following code

```
if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled ((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.userName.LaunchAtLoginHelperApp", YES)) {
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"An error ocurred"
                                     defaultButton:@"OK"
                                   alternateButton:nil
                                       otherButton:nil
                         informativeTextWithFormat:@"Couldn't add Helper App to launch at login item list."];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

The above code I have done on the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of my Main Application

Now, lets come to *LaunchAtLoginHelperApp*, on its `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I have the following code

```
BOOL alreadyRunning = NO;
    BOOL isActive = NO; // my modification
    NSArray *running = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
    for (NSRunningApplication *app in running) {

        if ([[app bundleIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"com.userName.LaunchAtLoginApp"]) {
            alreadyRunning = YES;
            isActive = [app isActive];
        }
    }

    if (!alreadyRunning || !isActive) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSArray *p = [path pathComponents];
        NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:p];
        [pathComponents removeLastObject];
        [pathComponents removeLastObject];
        [pathComponents removeLastObject];
        [pathComponents addObject:@"MacOS"];
        [pathComponents addObject:@"LaunchAtLoginApp"];
        NSString *newPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:pathComponents];
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:newPath];
    }
    [NSApp terminate:nil];
```

Now, lets come to settings that I have done in both apps

**LaunchAtLoginApp Settings**

I have copied the helper app in the **Build Phase>>Copy Files**
[image]

added `ServiceManagement.framework`

**LaunchAtLoginHelperApp**

I have made it background only application and set its skip installation to YES

Helper app is sandboxed

And Yes, I have put the application in `Application Folder` then run and restart the system but application did not launch it self.

Please let me know what have done wrong. Also, it would be great if you could tell me how to debug the issue.

P.S: There are some more frameworks that I am using in my main app

```
 WebKit.framework
 Sparkle.framework
 QuartzCore.framework
 SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: Try to register helper application first using LSRegisterURL((__bridge CFURLRef)urlToLoginHelper, true). urlToLoginHelper - its url ot helper which inside your bundle. Also in Console.app try to found logs related to login helper bundle identifier

Comment: @toohtik I just don't know how to thank you sir. Long live toohtik :) it worked but HOW??? please elaborate also please answer this question so other may also have the benefit of your intelligence.

Comment: Can we add this to other users as well. My app is multiuser and want it to open whenever any user logs in. Basically admin will install it and give it to user. When user logs in app should open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced with the same problem. And for me was very useful logs from the Console.app. I don't remember the exact text which was in the logs but error was something like: Can't locate bundle for identifier... 
So you need try to register url to helper application before SMLoginItemSetEnabled.

```
LSRegisterURL((__bridge CFURLRef)urlToLoginHelper, true)
SMLoginItemSetEnabled(...)
```

Seems that it was required by Apple's documentation but it was removed for some reasons later. And seems that right now you  [don't need register url for sandboxed apps](http://blog.mcohen.me/2012/01/12/login-items-in-the-sandbox/). But I haven't checked this suggestion.

Comment: Just asking.. u said that you used console.app to figure out the error. could you please tell me how did you do it? I am a newbie. It would be great if can tell me the whole process. Many thanks @toohtik

Comment: For example you can use something like that: http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/mac_os_x_using_console_to_troubleshoot_problems or http://www.macissues.com/2014/03/23/how-to-use-the-system-console-in-os-x/